# How can i meassure short distance inside buildings

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm new here im learning xcode and swift by myself and things are going well.

I wanted to ask what will be the best way (and most exact way) to measure short distances let's say up to 10 meters inside of a building so I cant use GPS
I want to get results in millimeters or centimeters.

Thank you for your time guys

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show some effort yourself. Having said that, don't bother, there isn't an exact way. You **might** be able to do something by combining the camera data and device motion but it won't be easy. You can't use device motion on its own to do this. Trying to find a link. one sec... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q_8d0E3tDk&list=UUj_UmpoD8Ph_EcyN_xEXrUQ&spfreload=10

Comment: I'd suggest a tape measure.  Or, if you want something fancy browse the tool aisles at Home Despot and look for a ultrasound distance gizmo (though be advised that most such devices are only accurate to a foot or so).

Comment: I havent try anything yet i had an idea and wanted to seeif it valid first...  I want to meassureusing device movment only

Comment: @MaorShabbat see the youtube link in my first comment.

Comment: For example iput the device on a table than move it to to the other side.... I want to meassure the distance between the starting point and the end point

Comment: I will now.  Thank you

Comment: Oh @Hot Licks this is what I love most about SO :) :D

Comment: In theory you should be able to use GPS signals to do this.  It's just that you need a GPS receiver that has an antenna good enough to work inside a building (which your standard iPhone does not).  You can augment this by adding your own beacon device -- this has been done by folks competing in various miniature autonomous vehicle contests.

Comment: @HotLicks would love a link about those competitions. Would be good to see what they did. Also, I thought GPS was only accurate down to around 3 metres. It doesn't matter what sort of aerial you have.

Comment: @Fogmeister - Last I read of this was several years ago.  But any site that covers "robot wars", miniature drones, and the like would probably have some link to it (and maybe even turn up a ready-made device).

Comment: @HotLicks I've seen some fairly up-to-date vids about autonomous drones and they all require an external camera to track their absolute position in the "world". Or an internal camera and some sort of range finder (laser, radar, etc...) to combine data with motion sensors.

Comment: @Fogmeister - For starters check out gpsworld.com.

Comment: @Fogmeister - GPS has cm accuracy, but there is "dither" introduced into the signal keyed to a secret encryption scheme (which US military equipment knows how to crack).  This "dither" is overcome by having a separate base station that decodes the GPS and rebroadcasts the amount of dither to the mobile device.

Comment: @HotLicks ah cool. Learned a lot. Thanks. Not sure how practical it is for measuring the length of a table though :P This is a good read also... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/what-is-the-maximum-theoretical-accuracy-of-gps

Answer (score 2):

Calculating distances based on device movement and using gyroscope, accelerometer, and other internal sensors is impossible.

There are a few reason why but see this link for an explanation...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q_8d0E3tDk&list=UUj_UmpoD8Ph_EcyN_xEXrUQ&spfreload=10

Comment: How about measuring pixels on device movment?

Comment: @MaorShabbat I'm not sure what that means. Can you explain it please.

Comment: So the inertial navigation systems we've trusted for decades to be able to guide missiles toward Russia are simply smoke and mirrors?

Comment: No, but I imagine GPS enabled, laser guided, multi-million dollar, inter-continental missile systems probably have more technology guiding them than an M7 co-processor. :-P

Comment: Just an idea... If i put the device on the a table and enable camera than move the device location can i meassur / count pixels than convert it to cm? Or anything like that

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested in my comment on your question. I don't think it would be possible with the camera flat onto the table (no light) but you could **potentially** do it. It would be very hard though.

Answer (score 0):

Use iBeacon and CoreLocation framework. Here is a video from last WWDC that touches this subject

[Taking CoreLocation Indoors](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/708xxvfd08bdof2/708/708_hd_taking_core_location_indoors.mov?dl=1)

Comment: The distance accuracy of iBeacon very coarse and generally insufficient for measuring distance with any accuracy.

Comment: How about measuring pixels on device movment? Is that possible? Can i convert pixels to cantimeters?

Comment: Core Location does not rely on iBeacon only. It uses other sensors of device and wifi. I strongly recommend you to watch WWDC video.

Comment: You can't do indoor location with iBeacons. Not like this anyway. You can tell if you're "roughly near" a beacon but even a book or your hand placed between the phone and the beacon will drastically change the reading. You can't do fine grain measurements like this. You can't even do triangulation.